# Q&A Webpart for Sharepoint

Tags: web-part

Is anyone aware of a Question and Answer webpart for sharepoint 2010+

I'm looking for similar functionality to the Stack Network rather than a forum.

The audience for this site will consist of scientists asking questions of other scientists across disciplines. They will be seeking authoritative answers to their questions and building a knowledge base for the future.

For security reasons we're unable to take advantage of any API's.

We've looked at NewsGator Social Sites, but it's *too* social for our needs and Forum products like Social Squared won't generate authoritative enough answers to build a knowledge base.

Comment: Here is a link to some stack exchange clone, if that helps; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are pretty limited if you don't want a forum-based solution in SharePoint 2010 with no API access. To keep things super simple with these constraints in mind, I would just create two lists; a Question list and an Answer list. The Question list would consist of an ID field (the one SharePoint provides would work fine), and a Question field. In the Answer field, create a lookup field connected to the Question ID & Title fields so you can create a relationship between the two.

I would then use a couple of pages and skinned Data View Web Parts to make it look like they weren't using lists. You could also use a URL parameter to filter out unnecessary information so that you're always using one page, and using the URL to control what's being shown.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what we'll end up doing.

Answer (score 3):

A simple discussion board may work for your needs.  You can do a little bit of customization to one if you need additional information or filtering abilities...

If you are doing canned answers, you could just use a list.

Comment: This site will consist of PhD level experts asking questions of similarly qualified people i.e. people seek authoritative answers

Comment: If you are willing to go with 2013, the Community site provides a discussion board that allows for ratings.  This may help with the authoritative part...

Comment: The problem I have is that we specifically want to avoid forum style discussions as the network already has that functionality and it hasn't proved worthwhile. Equally we are being forced to use 2010 due to the lack of internal security vetting of 2013.

Answer (score 0):

as John Said, Your Best Bet is use the community Sites.
In SharePoint 2013, a Community Site is a new site template that provides a forum experience in the SharePoint environment. Use communities to categorize and cultivate discussions among a broad group of people across organizations in a company. Communities promote open communication and information exchange by enabling people to share their expertise and seek help from others who have knowledge in specific areas of interest. You can deploy a Community Portal to promote communities to users within your enterprise.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219805.aspx

Comment: What you and John say is true, the problem I have is that we specifically want to avoid forum style discussions as they won't be productive in this instance.